# How to get top K words distributed in N computers efficiently?

Tags: algorithm, responsive-design

Suppose we have many words distributed in N computers and we want the top 10 frequent words.
There are three approaches I can think of:

1. Count the words on each N computer seperately and we can get top 20(This number can be discussed) words on each computer. Than merge these result together.

   The drawback of this approach is some words might be ignored. These words are distributed evenly on each computer but cannot be the Top 20 on each computer, but the total frequency of these words might be top 10.
2. It's almost the same as the first one. The difference is getting all the counting results on each computer and merge them. Then calculate the TOP 10.

   The drawback is the merge time and transmission time is relatively large.
3. Use a good hash function to redistribute the words. Different computer will not have same word. Then we can get TOP 10 on each computer and merge them.

   The drawback is every word will be hashed and transmit to another computer. It will take much transmission time.

Do you have any better approach for this? Or which one of my approaches is the best?

Comment: I think it's quite clear.

Answer (score 2):

Your idea in #1 was good but needed better execution. If F is the frequency of the Kth most common word on a single computer, then all words with frequency less than F/N on all N computers can be ignored. If you divide the machines into G groups, then the threshold F'/G applies, where F' is the frequency of the Kth most common word on the computers within a single group.

In two rounds, the computers can determine the best value for F and then aggregate a small Bloom filter that hits on all frequent words and gives false positives on some others, used to reduce the amount of data to merge with approaches #2 and #3.

Answer (score 0):

The drawback of the first approach makes it a non-solution.

The second approach sends all results to a single machine for it to do all the work.

The third approach sends all results as well, but to multiple machines, **who then share the workload** (this is the important part) - the final results that gets sent to a single machine to be merged should be small in comparison to sending all word frequencies.

Clearly the third approach makes the most sense.